# how to filter array model inside UISearchBar in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an array model which is like this:

```
 class Assess_order_med_model
{
    var name:String!
    var id:String!
    init(name:String!,id:String!) {
     self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

and i want to filter my array based on the "id" .for this i am doing like this.

```
 var filteredData = [Assess_order_med_model]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table_View.dataSource = self
        table_View.delegate  = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.table_View.allowsSelection = false
        let array_vale1 = Assess_order_med_model.init(name: "New York, NY", id: "1")
               self.array_model.append(array_vale1)
                filteredData = array_model

    }
```

and now i am filtering my array like this

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? array_model : array_model.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it

            return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })

        table_View.reloadData()
    }
```

**but it is giving me error like this: value of type Assess_order_model has no member range**.
Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong while doing filtering?

Comment: If you are doing search on the name, you can do it like: `array_model.filter { $0.name.contains(searchStr) }`. If you are looking for search/ filter on basis of `id`, then also you can filter like this just use `$0.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array_model` contains objects `Assess_order_med_model`, change your `textDidChange searchText` like below,

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let searchString = searchText.trimWhiteSpace()
    if searchString != "", searchString.count > 0 {
        let filterData = array_model.filter {
            return $0.id?.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        }
    }
}
```

this is the generic method to `trimWhiteSpace`,

```
extension String {
    func trimWhiteSpace() -> String {
        let string = self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return string
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @ppl your code is working fine. and i have changed your code to like this due to some minor bugs.func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let searchString = searchText.trimWhiteSpace()
        
        filteredData = searchString.isEmpty ? array_model : array_model.filter {
                return $0.name?.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
       
        table_View.reloadData()
    }

Comment: i was facing issue related to filtering...eg if i was typing "new" it was showing results but when i removing 1 character like "ne" it was not refereshing the tableview list

Comment: what searchtext you are getting?

Comment: once i searched something it showed me results but when i retype something inside searchbar list was not refreshing.

Comment: First of all, pease use if else condition in case of long code structure

Comment: func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let searchString = searchText.trimWhiteSpace()

        if searchString != "", searchString.count > 0 {
            filterData = array_model.filter {
                return $0.name?.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
        } else {
            filterData = array_model
        }
        
        table_View.reloadData()
    }

Comment: try the above code please and please do upvote also, so it may be helpful to others as well and let me know in case of any further queries

Comment: is it so? don't know why it is not working but any way remove it